# rbind 4 dataframe and remove specific string in R

Tags: r

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

A <-data.frame(V1=c("Amy", 1:6), V2=c("Grade", 1:6), V3=c("level", LETTERS[1:6]))
B <-data.frame(V1=c("Mike", 1:6), V2=c("Grade", 1:6), V3=c("level", LETTERS[1:6]))
C <-data.frame(V1=c("Kevin", 1:6), V2=c("Grade", 1:6), V3=c("level", LETTERS[1:6]))
D <-data.frame(V1=c("Grace", 1:6), V2=c("Grade", 1:6), V3=c("level", LETTERS[1:6]))

df <- A %>% rbind(B, C, D) %>% setnames(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), c("ID", "Grade", "level"))
```

I have 4 dataframe need to merge, the code above will keep value what I want to remove.
I want ask about maybe have more effective way?

I want to replace Grade and level by NA or space.
[image]

Comment: I'd go back and step and revise how you made `A`,`B`,`C` and `D`. It looks like you forgot to tell the import script (`read.csv`? `read_csv`? `fread`?) that the first row is the header/column names.

Comment: @thelatemail , hi, they come from fread.

Comment: Try `fread("file.csv", header=TRUE)` for each file.

Comment: The default for `fread` is already `header=TRUE`, so I wonder if perhaps there's something else ... are the CSV files well-structured? I can reproduce this when the first line of the file has just commas, such as when the data is exported from Excel (or Calc ...) and an empty leading row is accidentally included. If that's the case, consider `read.csv(.., skip=1, header=TRUE)` (similarly for `fread`).

Comment: The default for `fread` is "auto" over here, which will default to TRUE if every column name is character. So possibly a blank line might be causing the issue as it's preventing the automatic header detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question, but, assuming you want to keep the structure you show in the image, and you only want to replace the values indicated by `NA` or a white space `(" ")` you can first locate the position where these values are and assign by the character you want:

```
df[which(df=="Grade" | df == "level", arr.ind = T)] <- " "
```

You can use white space (" ") or NA. The output is:

```
> df
      ID Grade level
1    Amy            
2      1     1     A
3      2     2     B
4      3     3     C
5      4     4     D
6      5     5     E
7      6     6     F
8   Mike            
9      1     1     A
10     2     2     B
11     3     3     C
12     4     4     D
13     5     5     E
14     6     6     F
15 Kevin            
16     1     1     A
17     2     2     B
18     3     3     C
19     4     4     D
20     5     5     E
21     6     6     F
22 Grace            
23     1     1     A
24     2     2     B
25     3     3     C
26     4     4     D
27     5     5     E
28     6     6     F
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider turning the name into a column. It'll probably be better for further analysis.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor) # Handy row_to_names function

list(A, B, C, D) |> 
  lapply(\(x) row_to_names(x, row_number = 1)) |>
  Reduce(bind_rows, x = _) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Grade, level), values_drop_na = TRUE, values_to = "ID")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 24 × 4
   Grade level name  ID   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 1     A     Amy   1    
 2 2     B     Amy   2    
 3 3     C     Amy   3    
 4 4     D     Amy   4    
 5 5     E     Amy   5    
 6 6     F     Amy   6    
 7 1     A     Mike  1    
 8 2     B     Mike  2    
 9 3     C     Mike  3    
10 4     D     Mike  4    
11 5     E     Mike  5    
12 6     F     Mike  6    
13 1     A     Kevin 1    
14 2     B     Kevin 2    
15 3     C     Kevin 3    
16 4     D     Kevin 4    
17 5     E     Kevin 5    
18 6     F     Kevin 6    
19 1     A     Grace 1    
20 2     B     Grace 2    
21 3     C     Grace 3    
22 4     D     Grace 4    
23 5     E     Grace 5    
24 6     F     Grace 6
```